# VB.NET and IEnumerable

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable, ienumerator, exchange-sharp

I'm new to VB.NET and am not getting the syntax like I want.

Using this library:
https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp

I'm trying to iterate through open orders.

```
Dim openOrders As IEnumerable(Of ExchangeOrderResult) = api.GetOpenOrderDetails()
```

This doesn't give me an error, but anything I try and do with the variable it just says "invalid command"
All of these don't work and I'm not sure how to iterate over this.

```
Console.WriteLine(openOrders.Count)
'also tried this

    Dim enumerator As IEnumerator(Of ExchangeOrderResult) = openOrders.GetEnumerator
    While (enumerator.MoveNext) 'crashes here
    End While
```

I don't understand VB syntax and I've been searching for an hour or two, so I've given up for now.
Any help appreciated!

#### Edit

I'm using the poloniex API.

This is the stack trace I'm getting from any example/attempt at this:

> ExchangeSharp.APIException occurred HResult=0x80131500 Message=Invalid command. Source=ExchangeSharp StackTrace: at ExchangeSharp.ExchangePoloniexAPI.CheckError(JToken result) at ExchangeSharp.ExchangePoloniexAPI.MakePrivateAPIRequest(Stri‌​ng command, Object[] parameters) at ExchangeSharp.ExchangePoloniexAPI.d__26‌​.MoveNext() at ConsoleApp3.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\KMS10\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Module1.‌​vb:line 42

Comment: Please edit your question and post the stack trace of the exception you are getting.

Comment: Which API are you using? The source code for the [`ExchangeKrakenAPI` (from the example on the README) just calls the base class which throws a `NotImplementedException`](https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp/blob/master/ExchangeSharp/API/Exchanges/ExchangeKrakenAPI.cs#L386).

Comment: I'm using the poloniex API.
This is the stack trace I'm getting from any example/attempt at this:

'ExchangeSharp.APIException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Invalid command.
  Source=ExchangeSharp
  StackTrace:
   at ExchangeSharp.ExchangePoloniexAPI.CheckError(JToken result)
   at ExchangeSharp.ExchangePoloniexAPI.MakePrivateAPIRequest(String command, Object[] parameters)
   at ExchangeSharp.ExchangePoloniexAPI.<GetOpenOrderDetails>d__26.MoveNext()
   at ConsoleApp3.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\KMS10\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Module1.vb:line 42
'

Comment: This isn't an issue with your loop. According to the stack trace, [this line](https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp/blob/master/ExchangeSharp/API/Exchanges/ExchangePoloniexAPI.cs#L75) is failing because of an unexpected (invalid?) response from the API. I suggest you contact the maintainer of the library and/or look at the documentation for & response from the Poloniex API to find out why the request/response isn't being processed correctly, fix it, and if the problem is on their end submit a GitHub pull request to patch it.

Answer (score 0):

Use For Each to iterate over an IEnumerable. Make sure you've imported System.Collections.Generic:

```
Dim openOrders As IEnumerable(Of ExchangeOrderResult) = api.GetOpenOrderDetails()

For Each openOrder In openOrders
    ...
Next
```

Comment: Just getting invalid command from this. I tried stuff like this already from examples and was wondering why it wasnt working. Any idea why it's so difficult to iterate over this IEnumerable??

Answer (score 0):

An enumerable is similar to a collection, except the only way to read the contents is to loop through it. VB.NET has the [For Each...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) structure that can be used for this.

```
For Each item As ExchangeOrderResult In openOrders
    ' Do something with item variable
Next
```

Comment: Still not working :(
        Dim openOrders As IEnumerable(Of ExchangeOrderResult) = api.GetOpenOrderDetails()
        For Each item As ExchangeOrderResult In openOrders 'ExchangeSharp.APIException: 'Invalid command.'
            ' Do something with item variable
        Next